# Elasticsearch > Is it possible to build indices on base of FIELDS

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

In the context of ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana), I learnt that Logstash has FILTER to make use of grok to divide log messages into different fields. According to my understanding, it only helps to make the unstructured log data into more structured data. But I do no have any idea about how Elasticsearch can make use of the fields (done by grok) to improve the querying performance? Is it possible to build indices on base of the fields like in traditional relational database?

Answer (score 0):

From [Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html)

```
Inverted index

Relational databases add an index, such as a B-tree index, to specific columns in 
order to improve the speed of data retrieval. Elasticsearch and Lucene use a 
structure called an inverted index for exactly the same purpose.

By default, every field in a document is indexed (has an inverted 
index) and thus is searchable. A field without an inverted index is 
not searchable. We discuss inverted indexes in more detail in Inverted Index.
```

So you not need to do anything special. Elasticsearch already indexes all the fields by default.